# Textjoin on table with search and isnumber, on multiple rows and columns, needed to be unique and sorted

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two tables (A and B).

[image: Table B is a schedule of sorts. Table A is a summary of Table B.]

The formula I use now in table A (next to DE, N22) is:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",";TRUE;IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(M22;$Q$31:$X$35));$Q$30:$X$30;""))
```

The Isnumber and Search was added to be able to find the separate country codes in a cell with several, ex DE-SE.

I've tried to add Unique and Sort, in different places in the formula, but not getting it to work.

The problem I'm having is I get results that is not sorted and with duplicates.
**Result now:** CW12,CW13,CW15,CW16,CW05,CW04,CW13,CW15,CW05,CW12,CW04,CW04

I would like to have only unique values, and preferably sorted the same way as the CW-row (Q30:X30) is formatted.
**Wanted Result:** CW12,CW13,CW15,CW16,CW04,CW05

Markdown Data:

**Table B**

| CW12 | CW13 | CW14 | CW15 | CW16 | CW17 | CW04 | CW05 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DE | SE-DE | NO | DE-SE | DE | SE-GB | NO | SE-DE |
| SE | GB | JP | IE | SE | GB | DE | GB |
| SE | DE | NO | DE | SE | IE | NO | DE |
| DE | FI | SE | JP | NO | CN | DE | FI |
| FI | FI | IE | JP | NO | CN | DE-HU | FI |

**Table A**

| TABLE A |  |
| --- | --- |
| DE | CW12,CW13,CW15,CW16,CW04,CW05 |
| SE | CW12,CW13,CW14,CW15,CW16,CW17,CW05 |
| GB | CW13,CW17,CW05 |
| FI | CW12,CW13,CW05 |
| NO | CW14,CW16,CW04 |

Any ideas?

Comment: If you add your sample data as text within your question (best by using [Markdown Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) (read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/16578424) for an explanation) it is much easier to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Functions**:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=MAP(A1:A5,LAMBDA(x,TEXTJOIN(", ",,UNIQUE(TOCOL(IFS(FIND(x,C8:J12),C7:J7),3,1)))))
```

---

**Python**:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
[', '.join(filter(None,[h if s in str(v) else '' for h, v in xl("C7:J12", headers=True).items()])) for s in xl("A1:A5")[0]]
```

---

For those interested to solve this, some markdown data:

| CW12 | CW13 | CW14 | CW15 | CW16 | CW17 | CW04 | CW05 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DE | SE-DE | NO | DE-SE | DE | SE-GB | NO | SE-DE |
| SE | GB | JP | IE | SE | GB | DE | GB |
| SE | DE | NO | DE-SE | SE | EI | NO | DE |
| DE | FI | SE | JP | NO | CN | DE | FI |
| FI | FI | IE | JP | NO | CN | DE-HU | FI |

Comment: Thank you, this solves my issues. I ended up incapsulating the formula in an IFERROR as well since I have country codes in my big Table A, that is not planed in Table B, which resulted in a calculation error.

=IFERROR(MAP(C4:C49;LAMBDA(x;TEXTJOIN(",";;UNIQUE(TOCOL(IFS(FIND(x;DraftPlan);DraftPlanCW);3;1)))));"")

Answer (score 1):

Try something along the lines of:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C2</kbd>

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",,UNIQUE(TOCOL(IFS(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B2,$F$11:$M$15)),$F$10:$M$10),3,1)))
```

---

You might need to change the cell references and ranges accordingly as per your data. As well commas to semicolon.

---

You can also return it as a single dynamic array formula using a <kbd>LAMBDA( )</kbd> helper function like <kbd>BYROW( )</kbd> or <kbd>MAP( )</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C2</kbd>

```
=MAP(B2:B6,LAMBDA(α,
  TEXTJOIN(",",,UNIQUE(TOCOL(IFS(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(α,$F$11:$M$15)),$F$10:$M$10),3,1)))))
```

---